# How to use Kafka data source in Jupyter notebook?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, spark-structured-streaming

I use Jupyter notebook to run the following streaming query using Spark Structured Streaming.

The script throws a `StreamingQueryException`. How could I fix this?

Here are versions of the programs that I use:

- Spark: 2.4.3
- Scala: 2.11
- KAFKA: 2.1.1

I also used additional jar files:

- spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.4.3.jar
- kafka-clients-2.1.1.jar

Here is the Spark consumer code:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('Test').getOrCreate()

sdf = (
    spark.readStream.format('kafka')
    .option('kafka.bootstrap.servers', '10.142.0.11:9092')
    .option('subscribe', 'Test')
    .option('startingOffsets', 'earliest')
    .load()
)

query=sdf.writeStream.queryName('Test').format('console').outputMode('append').start()

query.awaitTermination()
```

Here is the stack error I got

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:

/opt/conda/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o64.awaitTermination.
: org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryException: Writing job aborted.
=== Streaming Query ===
Identifier: Test [id = 156da0ad-b499-4e2a-ba56-7ca6c2fb5c2a, runId = 4723816d-7205-401f-b279-f7e0b25de631]
Current Committed Offsets: {}
Current Available Offsets: {KafkaV2[Subscribe[Test]]: {"Test":{"0":180051}}}

Current State: ACTIVE
Thread State: RUNNABLE

Logical Plan:
KafkaV2[Subscribe[Test]]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:297)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:193)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Writing job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.doExecute(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.getByteArrayRdd(SparkPlan.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollect(SparkPlan.scala:296)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3383)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2782)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2782)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$53.apply(Dataset.scala:3364)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3363)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collect(Dataset.scala:2782)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$runBatch$5$$anonfun$apply$17.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:540)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$runBatch$5.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:535)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:351)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$runBatch(MicroBatchExecution.scala:534)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(MicroBatchExecution.scala:198)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:351)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1.apply$mcZ$sp(MicroBatchExecution.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProcessingTimeExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runActivatedStream(MicroBatchExecution.scala:160)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:281)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, spark-cluster-w-0.us-east1-c.c.dynamas-dev.internal, executor 2): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaMicroBatchInputPartition
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream$$anon$1.resolveClass(JavaSerializer.scala:67)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1868)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1751)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2042)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2287)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2211)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2287)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2211)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:376)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1890)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1878)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1877)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1877)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2111)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2060)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2049)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:737)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2061)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.doExecute(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:64)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaMicroBatchInputPartition
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream$$anon$1.resolveClass(JavaSerializer.scala:67)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1868)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1751)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2042)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2287)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2211)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2287)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2211)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:376)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

StreamingQueryException                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-885fef5a9f37> in <module>
----> 1 query.awaitTermination()

/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/streaming.py in awaitTermination(self, timeout)
    101             return self._jsq.awaitTermination(int(timeout * 1000))
    102         else:
--> 103             return self._jsq.awaitTermination()
    104 
    105     @property

/opt/conda/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1255         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1256         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1258 
   1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     73                 raise ParseException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
     74             if s.startswith('org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryException: '):
---> 75                 raise StreamingQueryException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
     76             if s.startswith('org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecutionException: '):
     77                 raise QueryExecutionException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)

StreamingQueryException: 'Writing job aborted.\n=== Streaming Query ===\nIdentifier: Test [id = 156da0ad-b499-4e2a-ba56-7ca6c2fb5c2a, runId = 4723816d-7205-401f-b279-f7e0b25de631]\nCurrent Committed Offsets: {}\nCurrent Available Offsets: {KafkaV2[Subscribe[Test]]: {"Test":{"0":180051}}}\n\nCurrent State: ACTIVE\nThread State: RUNNABLE\n\nLogical Plan:\nKafkaV2[Subscribe[Test]]'
```

Comment: Please show how you added the jar files. Also, you need to remove the kafka-clients jar because it conflicts with Spark

Comment: I added jar file in `/usr/lib/spark/jars` directory.

Comment: @cricket_007 When I remove the kafka-clients jar I get this error `Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o84.load.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider$`

Comment: @cricket_007 the error above happens while loading the stream `spark.readStream.....load()`

Comment: The error is caused by `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer`

Comment: And you've restarted the kernel after adding your JAR files? And SPARK_HOME is defined as /usr/lib/spark?

Comment: Hmm okay... Scala and Java don't need kafka-clients because it's a transitive dependency. Feel free to add it back

Comment: Yes, I restart the kernel every adding jar file.

Comment: I looked at the git repository [link](https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/master/external/kafka-0-10-sql/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/kafka010) of spark-sql-kafka and I didn't see the class `KafkaMicroBatchInputPartition`. Is it normal?

Comment: You have to look at the 2.4.3 branch, since that's the version you're using. https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.3/external/kafka-0-10-sql/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/kafka010/KafkaMicroBatchReader.scala#L324

Answer (score 0):

Kafka data source is in `spark-sql-kafka-0-10` external module that is distributed with the official distribution of Apache Spark, but is not included in the CLASSPATH by default.

You should run your Spark application using `--packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.4.3` that will add all necessary classes (incl. Kafka ones).

You should not add any jars yourself as you are going to miss some transitive dependencies (and get very weird `ClassNotFoundExceptions`). Please avoid *"I also used additional jar files"* and remove them.

---

`org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaMicroBatchInputPartition` is available in the repo at [KafkaMicroBatchReader.scala#L324-L329](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.3/external/kafka-0-10-sql/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/kafka010/KafkaMicroBatchReader.scala#L324-L329).